# Exponential decay and integration

Tags: integration, exponential-function, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

I am confronted with the following problem:

> Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. We wish to show that for any $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the integral 
>   $$ F(r):= \int_0^{\infty} |u|^p \exp \bigg\{ - \int_0^u \int_{-\infty}^{z+r} \, \mu(d \theta) \, dz \bigg\} \, du < + \infty.$$ 
>   Moreover,  we wish to show that $F$ is bounded over $r$.

Since $\mu$ is a probability measure, we clearly have 
$$ \bigg| \int_0^u \int_{-\infty}^{z+r} \, \mu(d \theta) \, dz \bigg| \leq |u|. $$ 
Therefore, we are done if there exist results concerning exponential decays of the form
$$  \int_0^{\infty} |u|^p \exp \big\{ -  \alpha(u) \big\} \, du ,$$
where $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ has linear growth. However, I really have problems proving it for the general case.